# How to change value of global variable using function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to change the value of a global variable using a function.

Here is my js code:

```
var name="Samir";
var status=true;

function func1 () {
    status=false;
    name="sunny"
}


func1();

console.log(name);
console.log(status);
```

This works fine, but I was curious about how to implement the same functionality using typescript. Please guide me

Comment: what is the point of passing arguments?

Comment: Typescript is wrapping type checking over JavaScript. The compiler would throw error as `func1` do not have any arguments in it's definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare global {
   name: string;
   status: boolean;
}
function func1 () {
    globalThis.status = false;
    globalThis.name = "sunny"
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is a poorly constructed example that works in JavaScript but not in valid in TypeScript.

Check the code here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FANwhgTgBAdmC2BTAvAIgMoIJYVQblEigGcAXMUgV2OVIksQOADNKYBjUrAexilY4BGKAAoAlFADewKLJLkqNZmAA2xRjLlwkaYmxgBPVMAC+wcwPaCR2xABoyFamKbtexbisQA6FdwDmNgiILsBuMB5evgEijoqhQA)

The errors are

1. Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.'
2. Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'status' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'boolean'.
3. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
4. Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant.

Valid JS code will be,

```
let userName = "Samir";
let userStatus = true;

function func1 (userName, userStatus) {
    userStatus = userStatus;
    userName = userName;
}

func1("sunny", false);

console.log(userName);
console.log(userStatus);
```

Any valid JavaScript will pass through the TS compiler. *TypeScript is a strongly typed programming language that builds on JavaScript*.

Make it type-safe by changing your function signature to

```
function func1 (userName: string, status: boolean)
```

Comment: "TS is a superset of JS" << however it may in edge cases change the meaning of expressions, that's a tiny caveat to watch out for. For example `x<string>(y)` will be compiled to `x(y)` even though `x<string>(y)` is valid JS code itself (albeit most likely nonsensical - it essentially means `(x < string) > y`).

Comment: Typescript is not a superset of Javascript. People should really stop saying that. We still struggle today to make perfectly well formed and working Javascript compile or get proper type inference, making many patterns (usually functional ones) impossible or discouragingly hard to express.

Comment: I will alter my line. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript). *It (TypeScript) is a strict syntactical superset of JavaScript and adds optional static typing to the language

Answer (score 0):

[`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) are actually `window` properties. All you need to do is use different names and TS will not complain.

[updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FANwhgTgBA+gdmAtgUwLwCIDKSCWF0DcoksAzgC5jkCupq5E1yRwAZtXAMbk4D2cUdlwCMUABQBKKAG9gUeWUo06rMABtSzOQvhI06UhzgBPdMAC+wNh07DJLTv1K81yAHRreAczG6UEokc4Z1cPb18KKloA4CA)